# Type Conversion in C going Bananas?

Tags: c, casting, printf

It seems that C and I disagree on the expected output here.

I have:

```
struct r_struct {
    int r_i;
    float r_f, r_f2;
};

struct r_struct r;

r.f = 100.0;

[...]
printf("f is A:%f B:%d, C:%d, D:%d\n", r.f, r.f, r.f_lhzr / 1, (int)r.f);
```

I am getting this output:

`f is A:100.000000 B:0, C:1079574528, D:0`

I expect to get this output as the float should be casted in all three ways to integer:

`f is A:100.000000 B:100, C:100, D:100`

Can someone here explain this?

Comment: what result did you expect instead?

Comment: `relais.r_lhzr` is a `float` value, and all the calculations you perform with it will result in floating point values. You can't use the `%d` formatting specifier as it's for `int` values. Mismatching format specifier and argument type results in *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Edited for better readability.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I know. But I cast them, why does this not work?

Comment: You only cast ***one*** of the `printf` arguments, the rest are still `float` values that you attempt to print using `%d`.

Comment: @Christian i guess the edited code doesn't compile. Would this be what you do:
```
    float value = 100.0;
    printf("%f\n",value);
    printf("%d\n",value);
    printf("%d\n",value/1);
    printf("%d\n",(int)value);
```

Comment: ... and that results in UB. End of explanation. Isn't that the only needed answer? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
Well, I don't think so...
First %f matches float and prints fine. 
Second %d matches r.f and afaik it should cast automatically.
Third is the result of "float / int) and should be casted to int automatically, too.
Forth explict casts by using (int) to int and therefore machtes %d, too.

Comment: No. It simply does not know how to "cast automatically". Format specifiers are just characters in a string, and mean nothing to the compiler.

Comment: Post the actual code. What is `r.f_lhzr` and where was it declared?

Comment: That's not how it works. The `printf` function know *nothing* about the arguments passed to it. It relies solely on the format specifiers you use in the string to interpret the memory occupied by those arguments. The compiler doesn't pass any kind of type-information along with the arguments.

Comment: Ok, got it so far. Is an issue of printf as it casts only based of format specifiers. And if given "%d" is reads binary and does not take care of type.

Comment: And to explain some terminology: a _cast_ is always done explicitly by the programmer with the `()` cast operator, it is never automatic. A _conversion_ is something that can either happen because of an explicit cast or because of one of the many implicit type conversion rules of C. And finally `printf` family of functions will convert the passed parameter to the passed conversion specifier. Hence the name conversion specifier. If it fails to do a correct conversion, `printf` will indeed go bananas.

Comment: The `...` in the prototype of `printf` after the format string parameter means that all the function arguments after the format string argument are converted according to the _default argument promotions_. The specifiers in the format string need to match the types of the corresponding arguments _after_ the default argument promotions have been applied. (Note that the default argument promotions do not convert `float` to `int`. They convert `float` to `double`.)

Comment: Another thing to be aware of for a mismatch between the format conversion specifier and the argument type is that different argument types may be passed to the function in different places. So it is not just a case of the binary value of the argument being interpreted differently - it may be interpreting the binary value at some other place where it expects the argument to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the spec of `printf()`, e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

> **If any argument** after default conversions **is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier**, or if there are fewer arguments than required by format, **the behavior is undefined**.

You have float values and only cast one to `int`.
You use `"%d"` specifier for floats, that is the end of any predictable or explainable behaviour, for all the output and any other behaviour, not only for the non-cast values.

(*The contrast between speficier and type was pointed out by SomeProgrammerDude in comments. I add the UB aspect with reference to spec here.*)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys.

Got it now! Thanks a lot.

I solved my issue by simply assigning the float to an int before printing. And the printf then prints the integer correct.

```
int i;

i=r.f; // or i=r.f/1; or i=(int)r.f;

printf("Correct float casted to int: %d\n",i);

/* Does NOT work by design. None of these:
printf("Wrong float casted to int: %d\n",r.f);
printf("Wrong float casted to int: %d\n",(int)r.f);
printf("Wrong float casted to int: %d\n",r.f/1);
*/
```

Comment: `(int)f` definitely works, alternatively you can give a float and use a float format specifier with a "precision" modifier like `"%.f"` (notice the dot)